# Subheading Bullet Question

Tags: pdf, cv

How do I remove the bullets that fall between the 2 lines under the **experience section**? I circled two of them in red on the image I attached. I’m unsure if editing the bullets in this section will ruin all of the bulleted lists in this document.[image: bullet question]

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,11pt]{article}

\usepackage{latexsym}
\usepackage[empty]{fullpage}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{marvosym}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{color}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage[pdftex]{hyperref}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{graphicx}

%-------------------------
% Custom commands
\newcommand{\resumeItem}[2]{
  \item\small{
    \textbf{#1}{ #2 \vspace{-2pt}}
  }
}

\newcommand{\resumeSubheading}[4]{
  \vspace{-1pt}\item
    \begin{tabular*}{0.97\textwidth}{l@{\extracolsep{\fill}}r}
      \textbf{#1} & #2 \\
      \textit{\small#3} & \textit{\small #4} \\
    \end{tabular*}\vspace{-5pt}
}

\newcommand{\resumeSubItem}[2]{\resumeItem{#1}{#2}\vspace{-4pt}}

\renewcommand{\labelitemii}{$\circ$}

\newcommand{\resumeSubHeadingListStart}{\begin{itemize}[leftmargin=*]}
\newcommand{\resumeSubHeadingListEnd}{\end{itemize}}
\newcommand{\resumeItemListStart}{\begin{itemize}}
\newcommand{\resumeItemListEnd}{\end{itemize}\vspace{-5pt}}


\begin{document}


\section{Experience}
 \resumeSubHeadingListStart
    \resumeSubheading
      {Clindata Insight}{Sf Bay Area}
      {Sr Manager Clinical Data Manager}{Jan 2020–Current}
      \resumeItemListStart
        \resumeItem{}
          {Leads the clinical data management (CDM) function and oversee vendor study data managers (SDM)}
             \resumeItem{}
        {Implements data cleaning processes, with identified critical queries/variables, and lead data cleaning topics at internal meetings until data base lock. }

          \resumeItemListEnd
          \resumeSubHeadingListEnd

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX SE. Could your provide the relevent code in the form of an [minimum working example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that)?

Comment: From your image, we have part of the code, but we would like to see a complete version of the code, starting with a `\documentclass{}` and ending with a `\end{document}`. We will then know what class you are using and where do the solid black bullet come from.

Comment: Is there a better way to display the MWE than how I pasted it above?

Comment: @acostaclindata: I have edited your question to improve the formatting of the example code. To do so, you can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (with "{}" on it).

Comment: If I try to compile the given code, Irecieve an error message "\begin{itemize} ... ended by \end{document}".

Comment: I added a line in. Is the error still showing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope it works dear friend! Just put an empty label into your `\item`.

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,11pt]{article}

\usepackage{latexsym}
\usepackage[empty]{fullpage}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{marvosym}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{color}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage[pdftex]{hyperref}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{graphicx}

%-------------------------
% Custom commands
\newcommand{\resumeItem}[2]{
  \item\small{
    \textbf{#1}{ #2 \vspace{-2pt}}
  }
}

\newcommand{\resumeSubheading}[4]{
  \vspace{-1pt}\item[]
    \begin{tabular*}{0.97\textwidth}{l@{\extracolsep{\fill}}r}
      \textbf{#1} & #2 \\
      \textit{\small#3} & \textit{\small #4} \\
    \end{tabular*}\vspace{-5pt}
}

\newcommand{\resumeSubItem}[2]{\resumeItem{#1}{#2}\vspace{-4pt}}

\renewcommand{\labelitemii}{$\circ$}

\newcommand{\resumeSubHeadingListStart}{\begin{itemize}[leftmargin=*]}
\newcommand{\resumeSubHeadingListEnd}{\end{itemize}}
\newcommand{\resumeItemListStart}{\begin{itemize}}
\newcommand{\resumeItemListEnd}{\end{itemize}\vspace{-5pt}}


\begin{document}


\section{Experience}
 \resumeSubHeadingListStart
    \resumeSubheading
      {Clindata Insight}{Sf Bay Area}
      {Sr Manager Clinical Data Manager}{Jan 2020–Current}
      \resumeItemListStart
        \resumeItem{}
          {Leads the clinical data management (CDM) function and oversee vendor study data managers (SDM)}
             \resumeItem{}
        {Implements data cleaning processes, with identified critical queries/variables, and lead data cleaning topics at internal meetings until data base lock. }

          \resumeItemListEnd
          \resumeSubHeadingListEnd

\end{document}
```

[image: Example]

Comment: Thank you this worked

Comment: Alright. Have a nice day `@acostaclindata`!